# Javascript each() function in newly added doms

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom

i use ajax to load some data into one of my divs , i have a each function that do not work on newly added doms , how can i bind it with something like "live" or "on" to take effects on newly added DOMs by ajax ?

```
$('ul.bigs > li').each(function(){
  console.log(this)
})
```

i mean "on" to something like :

```
$(document).on('click', '.header a', function() {
  //do something

})
```

Comment: Are you saying you've run the first block once on page startup, and you want the inner function to run at some arbitrary point in the future if more `li`s get added to `ul.bigs`?

Comment: i want to do console.log for newly added ul.big>li items , note that with my ajax when new data loaded old ul.big removed and new ul.bigs loaded to the page

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function and call it after you've appended the data to the DOM.

```
function update() {
  $('ul.bigs > li').each(function(){
    console.log(this)
  }) 
}

// Below is pseudo-code
$.ajax(..., function (data) {
  // Add the data to DOM
  update() // Call the update function at the end.
})
```

Comment: i try this before , but my problem is "$('ul.bigs > li').each(function()" do not get new Doms

Comment: How are you adding the data to the DOM?

Comment: get the result in ajax "success: function(data)" , remove old ul and add new ul and li (exist in ajax data variable)

Comment: I need to know what API you're using to insert the data into the DOM. Now you're just telling me how you get the data via AJAX.

Comment: document.getElementById("MyULContainer").innerHTML = data;

Comment: <div id="MyULContainer">
<ul class="bigs">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "newly added Doms"?

Because if you use something like `element.innerHtml = <div id='tst' >/div>` It won't work.

Since It does not update the DOM because you're just modifying a String.